# Add css style to option in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-select

I want to apply css style to option in select list.

It works perfect in mozilla firefox but does not apply in IE and chrome.

[jsfiddle for IE](https://jsfiddle.net/sachin214/kq51me1d/)

```
<select class="mapField">
   <option value="1">This is option 1 of select list</option>
   <option value="2">This is option 2 of select list</option>
   <option value="3">This is option 3 of select list</option>
</select>

<style>

select.mapField{
  width:120px;
}

.mapField option{
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   width: 100px;
}

</style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. `<option>` is rendered by the OS, and not HTML. Except for `background-color`, `color` and `border`, style settings applied through the style object for the option element are ignored. You can probably search for plugins that look like `<select>`, but are actually HTML elements that can be styled.

Comment: Thanks @Shobhit for help

Comment: Content which gives where we can add style to select list https://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-select-optgroup-options-css/